# Recursive Select runs slow

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a recursive Select, but the data is not really hierarchical and contains loops.
To prevent an endless loop I've added the trick to collect and check the path. But it's ultra slow,
even for a table with just 94 entries is it running forever - the real table has thousands of entries.
Any ideas to improve performance?

Update:
I have a large amount of approvals and have to split them into several packages. Each package should contain all requests for a user and a request can have mutliple users as approver. It doesn't matter where to start.

Here's a dbFiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d22f5c83ee6b3c8f960e0b5a29de8c8a

```
 WITH approvalpack (uniqueid, requestid, userid, chain) 
       AS (SELECT uniqueid, 
                  requestid, 
                  userid, 
                  Cast(uniqueid AS VARCHAR(max)) chain 
           FROM   approvals 
           WHERE  uniqueid = 1 
           UNION ALL 
           SELECT a1.uniqueid, 
                  a1.requestid, 
                  a1.userid, 
                  Cast(( chain + ',' + convert(varchar,a1.uniqueid) ) AS VARCHAR(max)) AS 
                  chain 
           FROM   approvals a1 
                  INNER JOIN approvalpack p1 
                          ON p1.userid = a1.userid
           WHERE  chain NOT LIKE '%,' + convert(varchar,a1.uniqueid) + ',%' 
                  AND chain NOT LIKE '%,' + convert(varchar,a1.uniqueid) + '%' 
                  AND chain NOT LIKE '%' + convert(varchar,a1.uniqueid) + ',%' 
                  AND chain <> convert(varchar,a1.uniqueid)
           UNION ALL 
           SELECT a1.uniqueid, 
                  a1.requestid, 
                  a1.userid, 
                  Cast(( chain + ',' + convert(varchar,a1.uniqueid) ) AS VARCHAR(max)) AS 
                  chain 
           FROM   approvals a1 
                  INNER JOIN approvalpack p1 
                          ON p1.requestid = a1.requestid 
           WHERE  chain NOT LIKE '%,' + convert(varchar,a1.uniqueid) + ',%' 
                  AND chain NOT LIKE '%,' + convert(varchar,a1.uniqueid) + '%' 
                  AND chain NOT LIKE '%' + convert(varchar,a1.uniqueid) + ',%' 
                  AND chain <> convert(varchar,a1.uniqueid)) 
  SELECT * FROM approvalpack
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve here? If you process the unique_id only once you will have an unpredictable behaviour.
Example: Number 2 can be reached using  1,2 or 1,3,2 or  1,4,5,6,3,2 or 1,4,5,6,3,2. 
Which one of these would you prefer?

Comment: I have a large amount of approvals and have to split them into several packages. Each package should contain all requests for a user and a request can have mutliple user as approver.
  My problem is that the select is slow, have you any ideas to improve performance?

Comment: The fact that an rCTE referenced mg itself not once, but twice, could well be the problem here. You're recursing on All the rows you've already reviewed on; I doubt you want that.

Answer (score 2):

For such recursion, I approach this be defining the pairs of unique ids -- and then recurse over the pairs.  That is, I eliminate the `userid` and `requestid` in the first step:

```
with pairs as (
      select distinct a1.uniqueid as uniqueid1, a2.uniqueid as uniqueid2
      from approvals a1 cross join
           approvals a2
      where a1.userid = a2.userid or a1.requestid = a2.requestid 
     ),
     cte as (
      select  uniqueid1, uniqueid2, 
             convert(varchar(max), concat(',', uniqueid1, ',', uniqueid2, ',')) as chain,
             1 as lev
      from pairs p
      union all
      select cte.uniqueid1, p.uniqueid2,
             concat(cte.chain, p.uniqueid2, ','), lev + 1
      from cte join
           pairs p
           on cte.uniqueid2 = p.uniqueid1
      where cte.chain not like concat('%,', p.uniqueid2, ',%') 
     )
select uniqueid1, min(uniqueid2)
from cte
group by uniqueid1
```

I figure you want a unique identifier in the end.  So this returns one row per unique identifier.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f4297d6afd9ba88776e59ca577e364fe) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Good approach - I will integrate this into my real use case and check with the real data.

Comment: I've tested your approach with my test table that has 94 entries. It still runs slow, I've stopped the execution after 2,5 h. If I add "lev < 3" to the Where-Clause of the pairs/cte-Join it runs 1,5 min - that would be acceptable but I'm not sure if it's enough to get all data.